# Howto derive statistical upper limit in case of zero observation of poisson process?

Tags: bayesian, outliers, count-data, poisson-process, monitoring

I am writing software, that keeps track of hourly rates of certain incidents in historic data. I find that the generating process of these incidents is acceptably well described by a poisson process.

As such, I estimate the intensity $\lambda$ from the historic data to be the hourly mean and subsequently raise an alert as soon as an observed event count (in real-time) exceeds some upper limit. I choose that upper limit such that it is still consistent with the historic event counts within probability $p=99.99$%, here I mean the event count where the distribution function reaches 0.9999.

Sometimes however, the historic data is limited in time and the observed event count is 0. I may need a different mechanism here.

As an example: If $\lambda=3$, then the probability of observing no events is $5$%. And with $\lambda=3$, an event count of 11 events in the same amount of time would still be consistent within $99.99$%. Hence, I'd put my upper limit at 12, but that is only for $\lambda=3$ ...

Given the observation of 0 events, the value of $\lambda$ has a distribution of its own. But how then do I derive an upper limit generally, can I simply take the expectation value like so:

$E_{\textrm{ul}}=\frac{\int\,\textrm{pmf}_{0}(\lambda)\cdot\,\textrm{ul}(\lambda)\,\textrm{d}\lambda}{\int\,\textrm{pmf}_{0}(\lambda)\,\textrm{d}\lambda}$

where pmf$_{0}(\lambda)$ is the probability mass function at $\lambda$ evaluated at an event count of 0 and ul$(\lambda)$ is the value of the distribution function at $p=0.9999$ (which leads to an expectation of 2.8)?

Or should I take the expectation of $\lambda$:

$E_{\lambda}=\frac{\int\,\lambda\,\textrm{pmf}_{0}(\lambda)\textrm{d}\lambda}{\int\,\textrm{pmf}_{0}(\lambda)\,\textrm{d}\lambda}$

and use that to derive the limit (leading to 5)?

I tried both approaches and they lead to different numbers ... **why is that**?

[image: Expectation value of upper limit in poisson process]

Comment: "*Given the observation of 0 events, the value of λ has a distribution of its own*" --  if you want to work in a Bayesian framework you should probably at least tag it as such

Comment: @Glen_b: Done, thanks. How do you think a frequentist would approach this?

Comment: if the graph on the top RHS is a pmf, why do the sum of the probabilities exceed one?

Comment: @Alex, all points in the right hand side plot "$\textrm{pmf}_{0}(\lambda)$" correspond to a *different* pmf (with different intensity $\lambda$). But they are all evaluated at an event count of $0$. They are my estimate of probability that the underlying generating process actually has that specific intensity $\lambda$, since my observation of the event count was $0$.